# Regex to capture a tuple containing a particular pattern from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
ee = [('noise', 0.7592900395393372), ('***roice***', 0.638433039188385), ('voice', 0.7524746060371399), ('***choice***', 0.638433039188385)]
```

From here I want to extract only the tuples that contains the pattern which starts with ***

Expected output:

```
ee = [('***roice***', 0.638433039188385), ('***choice***', 0.638433039188385)]
```

I have tried the following regex but it only captures the words with *** but not the entire tuple, i.e I also want the number present in the tuple which contains ***.

Code till now:

```
yy= []
for i in ee:
    t9 = re.findall("[***@*&?].*[***@*&?, ]", str(i))
#    for m in t9.finditer(t9):
#        print(m.start(), m.group())
#    
#    print(t9)
    for em in t9:
        yy.append(em)
```

Can someone help me fix this

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ee = [('noise', 0.7592900395393372), ('***roice***', 0.638433039188385), ('voice', 0.7524746060371399), ('***choice***', 0.638433039188385)]

output = []

for data in ee:
    if data[0].startswith("***")::
        output.append(data)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[('***roice***', 0.638433039188385), ('***choice***', 0.638433039188385)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want a regex in this case. If all that you want to do is filtering strings that begin with "***", you can simply do:

```py
[e for e in ee if e[0].startswith('***')]
```

If you still want to use a regex, you can do:

```py
r = re.compile(r'\*\*\*.*\*\*\*')
[s for s in ee if r.match(s[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to extract the tuples which 0 element starts and ends with `***`,
you can try with this:

```
extracted = []
for item in ee:
    if item[0][:3] == '***' and item[0][-3:] == '***':
        extracted.append(item)
```

This doesn't use regex.